# Angular: Child directive attribute binding only seeing initial values

Tags: angular

I have a `Parent` component and a `Child` directive. The `Parent` has an Array of integers passed to the `Child` through the attribute `events-data`.

The problem is that the ng-for loop can see the changes when the `Add` button is clicked (and an integer is added to the array) but the `onChange` function in the Child directive is never called again after the loading of the page. So the Child sees the initial content of the array but is never updated after that.

```
import {NgFor,Component,View, Directive, LifecycleEvent} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {routerDirectives} from 'angular2/router';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/di';

@Directive({
    selector:'child',
    lifecycle: [ LifecycleEvent.onChange ],
    properties: [ 'data: events-data' ]
})
export class Child{
    data: Array<number>;
    constructor() {
    }

    onChange(changes:{idx: string, PropertyUpdate}) {
        if (changes['data']) {
            console.log("DATA WAS UPDATED");
        }
    }
}

@Component({
    selector:'parent'
})
@View({
    template:`
    <child [events-data]="eventsData"></child>
    <button (click)="addValue()">Add</button>

    <li *ng-for="#ev of eventsData">
        {{ev}}
    </li>
    `,
    directives:[routerDirectives,Child,NgFor]
})
export class Parent{
    eventsData:Array<number>;

    constructor() {
        this.eventsData = [10,20,30,40,50,60];
    }
    addValue(){
        this.eventsData.push(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want the full explanaiton you can see it here : https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=55e27911017739836ed48109

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's your fix

```js
  addValue(){
    var array = this.eventsData.slice(0); // create array copy
    array.push(100); // mutate array copy
    this.eventsData = array; // replace ref
  }
```