# Angular2 LifecycleEvent.onChange Not Firing

Tags: javascript, angular

As of this writing, Im using Angular 2.0.0-alpha.36.
In the following code, everything functions as expected, EXCEPT for the onChange:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings-custom/_custom.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, LifecycleEvent} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    lifecycle: [LifecycleEvent.onInit, LifecycleEvent.onChange, LifecycleEvent.onCheck, LifecycleEvent.onAllChangesDone]
})
@View({
    template: '<button (click)="increment()">Increase Component {{count}}</button>'
})

export class Counter {

    count: number = NaN;

    constructor()
    {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    increment()
    {
        ++this.count;
    }

    onInit()
    {
        console.log('onInit');
    }

    onCheck()
    {
        console.log('onCheck');
    }

    onChange(changes)
    {
        console.log('onChange');
        console.log(changes);
    }

    onAllChangesDone()
    {
        console.log('onAllChangesDone');
    }
}
```

Aside from numerous Stack Overflow searches, I've referenced several threads including:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gtfY4C5mXJDhohEIVkSn?p=preview

http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292620/angular2-child-directive-attribute-binding-only-seeing-initial-values). You basically have to change the reference, not the value.

Answer (score 3):

`onChange()` gets triggered when there are changes in a component input bindings.

The problem is that the `Counter` component does not have input properties (input bindings), so that's why the on `onChange()` event is never called.

Comment: could you pls explain whats the diff. between Oninit and consturctor which one is called first ?

Comment: Constructor is called first, then on init AFIK

Comment: is Oninit called before template load or after the loading to template ?

Comment: The best way to find that out is to put a breakpoint in onInit and then check network tab of dev tools to see if the template request was issued (on mobile, cant try myself now)